# How can I zip transfer files to using Putty in Windows?

Tags: terminal, putty, dreamhost, pscp

I have a problem regarding transferring files from a server to another server. I tried using PSCP putty. it worked in the first time from local to server. what I'm trying to do is zip all files then transfer to another server. what commands should I use to achieve this?

```
    pscp -P 22 test.zip root@domain.com:/root
```

this line of code works when transferring local to remote server, however, I want to compress files from a server to another remote server, or at least remote to local, then local to remote, whatever method is possible. I cannot compress the files because it's almost 50 GB in total so I am searching for a much faster way to achieve this.

Comment: zip files from a directory-> transfer to another remote server or zip files from a server-> transfer to local-> transfer from local to remote server.

Comment: [scp and compress at the same time, no intermediate save](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70581/scp-and-compress-at-the-same-time-no-intermediate-save/70582)